# Python - move / upload specific files to FTPS

Tags: python, for-loop, wildcard, directory, ftps

I'm trying to implement a file transfer automation with python 2.7 on Windows.

So I have a FTPS server, I need to move some files from it to a local directory and to upload some files from local to FTPS

The FTPS structure is like so:

```
- ROOT FOLDER
    - AAA
        - abc_id1
            - in
            - out
        - abc_id2
            - in
            - out   
        - abc_id3
            - in
            - out
    - BBB
        - abc_id1
            - in
            - out
        - abc_id2
            - in
            - out   
        - abc_id3
            - in
            - out
```

I must first MOVE all files that match a wildcard ABC_*.csv, they are located in all /in folders (so for ex. AAA\abc_id1\in) to a local directory

Then I must upload (COPY) some files that have a wildcard from the local directory to the corresponding abc_/in folder (for ex. a file named ABC_id3.csv must go to the abc_id3 folder)

I have began the code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

ftps = FTP_TLS('ip_address')
ftps.login("user", "pass")           # login before securing control channel
ftps.prot_p()          # switch to secure data connection
#ftps.retrlines('LIST') # list directory content securely

ftps.cwd("AAA")
ftps.retrlines('LIST')



ftps.quit()
```

But I don't know how can i loop through the multiple folders to accomplish the task
Please suggest some code

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Two things that will help. Walking through directories with [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and [generators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators).
You'll want to walk through the directories and check each file going through. Once you determine it's a file you want you can apply the appropriate FTP functionality.

Here's a sample I have from one of my apps I'm working on. I've added the ability to exclude as well.

```
# Generator which runs through directories and returns files

def scanDir (self, root, excludeDirs, excludeFiles, excludeExt, maxFileSize):
    global fileList

    print "Scanning directory " + root
    x = 0
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):

            for name in filenames:
                #We want absolute path to these
                absroot = os.path.abspath(root)
                filename = os.path.join(absroot, name)
                fileSize = os.path.getsize(filename) / 1024
                x = x + 1
                #print x
                #@TODO compressed files call here (Extension)
                if (os.path.isfile(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0): 
                    if fileSize > maxFileSize:
                        continue
                    else:
                        try:
                            #print root + name
                            os.path.getsize(filename)
                            data = open(root + "/" + name, 'rb').read()
                        except:
                            data = False
                            print "Could not read file :: %s/%s" % (root, file)

                        # TODO Create Exception here and filter file paths:
                        # regex for /home/*/mail
                        self.fileList.append({"filename":filename})
                        yield data, filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of recursively walking an FTP server and fetching zip files, with an anonymous login.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep
import os

ftp = FTP('ftp2.census.gov')
ftp.login()

my_dirs = []  # global
my_files = [] # global
curdir = ''   # global

def get_dirs(ln):
  global my_dirs
  global my_files
  cols = ln.split(' ')
  objname = cols[len(cols)-1] # file or directory name
  if ln.startswith('d'):
    my_dirs.append(objname)
  else:
    if objname.endswith('.zip'):
      my_files.append(os.path.join(curdir, objname)) # full path

def check_dir(adir):
  global my_dirs
  global my_files # let it accrue, then fetch them all later
  global curdir
  my_dirs = []
  gotdirs = [] # local
  curdir = ftp.pwd()
  print("going to change to directory " + adir + " from " + curdir)
  ftp.cwd(adir)
  curdir = ftp.pwd()
  print("now in directory: " + curdir)
  ftp.retrlines('LIST', get_dirs)
  gotdirs = my_dirs
  print("found in " + adir + " directories:")
  print(gotdirs)
  print("Total files found so far: " + str(len(my_files)) + ".")
  sleep(1)
  for subdir in gotdirs:
    my_dirs = []
    check_dir(subdir) # recurse  

  ftp.cwd('..') # back up a directory when done here

try:
  check_dir('/geo/tiger/GENZ2012') # root directory to start in
except:
  print('oh dear.')
  ftp.quit()

ftp.cwd('/.') # change to root directory for downloading
for f in my_files:
  print('getting ' + f)
  file_name = f.replace('/', '_') # use path as filename prefix, with underscores
  ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, open(file_name, 'wb').write)
  sleep(1)

ftp.quit()
print('all done!')
```